# Dragging URLs to nodes in MindMeister mindmaps no longer works for me

Tags: mindmeister

I liked this feature very much, to drag a URL from the Firefox address bar to a mindmap and it would be clickable from a node. This feature was also once described [here](http://www.mindmeister.com/blog/2010/12/06/new-features-at-mindmeister-2/):

> From a different browser window, not tab, simply drag the URL to the
>   node that you’d like to link to, and presto – instant link insertion.
>   Say goodbye to copy/paste!

Now they rolled out a new version, and I noticed it does not work anymore. Instead I get this little error box after dropping the link on the node:

[image: error box]

Is there still a way to do it?

Comment: Are you trying to drag an image from another window into your mindmap or are you trying to create a link inside one of the nodes from a url in the address bar? Both seem to be working for me on MacOS: https://d.pr/free/v/EkSJLT